# call a method in some .cs file for Dropdownlistfor onchange event

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, dropdownlistfor

I have a static class ItemInitializer that has a method CreateCookie(). I want to call this method whenever the selected item in the dropdownlist change. How do I do that in mvc?

Currently, I am trying with this

In View:

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedItem, Model.MyItemList, new { @id = "ddLForItems"})
```

In Controller the method is called like this,

```
       myModel.SelectedItem = ItemInitializer.CreateCookie();
```

Now, onchange event for the DropDownListFor , the createCookie method needs to be called again.

With jquery, how do I call the CreateCookie method. I have,

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#ddLForItems").change(function () {
                    var item = $(this).val();
                    ...?

                   //TBD:Create a cookie with value myModel.SelectedItem 

                });
            });

</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `window.location.href` to redirect to a controller action on your application that will call this method:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#ddLForItems').change(function () {
            var item = $(this).val();
            var url = '@Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController")?value=' + encodeURIComponent(item);
            window.location.href = url;
        });
    });
</script>
```

which will redirect to the following controller action and pass the selected value to it:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(string value)
{
    ... you could call your method here
}
```

Alternatively if you don't want to be redirecting away from the current page you could use an AJAX call:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#ddLForItems').change(function () {
            var item = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { value: item },
                success: function(result) {
                    // the controller action was successfully called 
                    // and it returned some result that you could work with here
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Darin thank you very much. What I did was used  a GET instead of POST to suite SomeAction.